# On Post Token becomes null .net mvc6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have an [httpget] method which takes a token and stores it in Resetcode column of ResetPassword table.
[when [http Get] model takes the token value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPnSu.png).

[After password is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReKrJ.png) token takes a null value. P.s. I'm new to Asp.net

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
        {
            using (CiPlatformDbContext db = new CiPlatformDbContext())
            {
                var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ResetPasswordCode == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ResetPasswordVM vm = new ResetPasswordVM();
                    vm.ResetCode = id;
                    return View(vm);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
                }
            }

        }
```

```
[HttpPost]
        [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordVM obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (CiPlatformDbContext db = new CiPlatformDbContext())
                {
                    var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ResetPasswordCode == obj.ResetCode).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.Password = Crypto.Hash(obj.NewPassword);
                        user.ResetPasswordCode = "";
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword", "Changes committed successfully");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CI_Platform.Entities.Models;

public partial class PasswordReset
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "New password required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string? NewPassword { get; set; }


    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "New password and confirm password does not match")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string? ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    
    [Required]
    public string? ResetCode { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: Within your form in your view you could add `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ResetCode)` to retain the value between the GET and the next POST.

Comment: The reason for the null is because you used `new ResetPasswordVM()`, see my answer for more details.

Comment: @JasonPan DavidSpence 's comment worked for me. Thank you for your generosity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, in your code you have （`HttpPost` and `HttpGet`） ResetPassword method. These are two different methods. In your project, the HttpGet method is first executed, which means to find the ResetPassword page, click the submit button on the ResetPassword  page, and the form will be submitted to the ResetPassword of the HttpPost method.

The ResetPasswordVM model in the first HttpGet method is found according to the id, and I found that you used `new ResetPasswordVM()`;, so the model is a new entity data, and null is the expected behavior.

In your scenario,

```
var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ResetPasswordCode == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

After finding the user information, you should directly return to View(). You should not use this code

```
ResetPasswordVM vm = new ResetPasswordVM();
```